# How to add the new line in <pre/> using crayon syntax highlighter in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-highlighting, visual-composer

I am using the crayon syntax highlighter for syntax highlighting in wordpress blog. Problem is it print all of the code in single line with the 
 tag printed itself in the syntax instead of add the new line please help.

My Blog Page
[image: My blog page]

Problem
[image: Problem]

Code creating problem that needs to debug

```
<pre class="wp-block-preformatted lang:python decode:true" title="Shallow copy example"> 
import copy<br> l1 = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]<br> 
l2 = copy.deepcopy(l1)<br> print(l2) # [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]<br>
l1.append([7,8,9])<br> print(l1) #[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]<br> 
print(l2) #[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]<br> 
#now change in the old property of l1<br> 
l1[0][1] = “aa”<br> 
print(l1) #[ [1,”aa”,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]<br> 
print(l2) #[ [1,”2”,3], [4,5,6] ] so, here we see neither the new property is reflected in #this object nor the change in the first property reflected i,e,”aa”, l2[0][1] is 2 not #“aa”. </pre>
```

It should print like this code

Expected format of the visual syntax
[image: Expected output like this]